# Matrix notation with four subscripts - what does it mean?

Tags: matrices, notation

For the first time I've stumbled upon following notation:

$$  \Delta X_{ji} / X_{ijji}$$

It is described as *"given the percentage reduction in total inputs"*

Context: paper in economics. Describes manipulations for matrices that describe economic activitiy (e.g. in which sector i supplies a certain amount of goods to sector j).

Appreciate any help. I would guess it means

$$  \Delta X_{ji} / X_{ij} X_{ji}$$ but can someone verify?

Comment: But your guess simplifies to $1/X_{ij}$.

Comment: sorry I've missed the delta in the numerator.

Comment: 4-dimensional matrix?